# Nokogiri: add <tbody> after <table> elements as FireFox does

Tags: firefox, nokogiri

i have a problem:

Firefox adds `<tbody>` whether it's there or not, after `<table>`. I have no problem with this.
Nokogiri doesn't add it.

I need Nokogiri to emulate Firefox's behavior.

How can i add tbody after `<table>` elements to a given HTML page ? If tbody is already there, then move on to the next `<table>`....until all `<tbody>` tags are placed by Nokogiri.

Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate question? This seems to have been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680479/nokogiri-how-to-insert-tbody-tag-immediately-after-table-tag

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
require 'nokogiri'

src = <<EOS
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
EOS

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(src)

doc.xpath('//table').each do |table|
    tbody = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new('tbody', doc)
    tbody << table.children{|n| n.parent = tbody}
    table << tbody
end

puts doc
```